# Sushi rolls keep getting thin

Tags: rice, japanese-cuisine, sushi, salmon, thickness

I'm learning how to make sushi and the last problem I always get now is that my rolls end up getting too thin. I follow the guides I found on the internet to split the seaweed in half and put the amount of rice similar to a lemon sized ball. If I put an amount of rice and a normal sized filling, it is impossible to close.

So, I really would like to know a couple of things, what is the regular size for the seaweed, what is the proper amount of rice to put on it and if this problem I'm getting there's nothing to deal with measurements, but technique.

Note: as I see some tutorials, it seems the seaweed is the same, so they are getting the same size seaweed, and I'm inclined to believe that I'm executing the technique to roll improperly.

Comment: There's a fairly large variety of sushi rolls.   Half-nori sheet would be for "hosomaki" (thin rolls) or uramaki (inside out rolls): https://www.allaboutsushiguide.com/maki-sushi.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions, which have helped me.  First, cut your nori a bit larger.  Rather than using a half sheet, go for two-thirds a sheet.  Of course this will produce a smaller portion, for which you will need to devise a creative use (I've used them for hand rolls), but beginning with a larger sheet leaves you more room for error as you are learning to create consistent rolls.  Second, I like to try to create a layer of rice that is one grain of rice thick.  Of course, it doesn't always happen this way, but it allows me to work at keeping the rice layer uniform. Forget the "lemon-sized ball."  Just make a layer of rice, always leaving some exposed nori along the long edges so you can create a seal when you roll. Use a bowl of water to keep your hands moist, and avoid sticking rice. It does take some practice, so keep at it.  Once you are producing consistent results, you can go back to a half sheet.

Answer (score 1):

As it’s difficult to judge what size a given amount of rice will end up being once you roll it up, I follow a technique that I noticed a sushi chef doing on a video:

- put down a line of rice, then spread it out

You then have a much better clue how the rice will roll up (based on the width and height of the line of rice) and if you have it even across the length of the roll

You might need to experiment a little bit, based on how tightly you pack the rice when rolling, and how much else you’re adding as filling

Comment: Unless you pack a lot of fillings into your roll, on your first attempt aim for a line (ridge?) of rice roughly the size of the finished roll that you're aiming for, as you'll compress the rice as part of the rolling process.  You can then adjust your amounts (of rice and/or filling) for the subsequent rolls.